# JS/ Ruby for web application that requires data entry and storage as database tables

Tags: javascript, mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im using js and ruby on rails for front/back end.

How do I create a data entry page (webpg) which will appear as a list of items (vertically list down) on the webpg that is in a table form, with various time period as the other table variable (horizontal)? Currently I have a solution but requires a rather clunky input page where I click add button and add new line to enter but theres no way to visually make the tables easier to view, everything is like a lump of text.

Also how do I have it auto save and do calculations just like how Google spreadsheet does that is live and updated every now and then?

I just learnt programming so please forgive me for my unpolished question and feel free to clarify any part of my queries.

Many thanks!

Comment: If you can provide your effort code, it would be great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

> Also how do I have it auto save and do calculations just like how
>   Google spreadsheet does that is live and updated every now and then?

You need to set up some sort of perpetual connection between your server & input pages. It will be a tricky process, but is achievable

---

**HTTP**

Rails is based on the [HTTP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), which means that it will respond with data each time you send a request. This means it's not designed to deliver "live" / "perpetual connection" content to the front-end

To achieve live functionality, you'll have to use extra technology - namely [websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) or [SSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events)'s, to enable your application to receive updates from the server

---

**Perpetual Connection**

To achieve the functionality you want, you'll need to connect to your Rails app with a [pub/sub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) system. This is a front-end system (typically through JS), where your app's pages will load up & run a Javascript [EventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener) to "listen" for updates from your server

You'll then need to use something like [ActionController::Live](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Live.html), or a third-party script, to send updates to the channel you're subscribed to

This allows you to send updates to the server (via ajax), the server will then be able to process the updates, send returned data through the perpetual connection

---

I can write more about this if it's what you want